# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'NSIndexPath' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am showing data in a tableview and I added a show segue on it's `TableViewCell` click I in order to move to `DetailsController` and pass the data of the cell with the clicked `IndexPath` to the other controller in parameters.
This is the segue code :

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
    let indice = indexPath.row as NSInteger
    let nomCandidat = "candidats"

    let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
    detailsViewController.idtrip = 10
}
```

I made sure that the segue identifier is correct.

Error:

> Could not cast value of type `UITableViewCell` to `NSIndexPath`

Comment: Make sure you don't have a segue linked from the prototype cell object to your destination view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send `indexPath` as a sender parameter. The `sender:` is the UI element that triggered the segue, which in this case is a UITableViewCell.
So, you send the tableViewCell instance in the sender like:

```
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexPath: indexPath) else {return}
//alternatively 
//let cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexPath: indexPath)! 
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: cell)
```

Comment: You **do** can send `indexPath` as a sender parameter if the origin of the segue is the view controller.